# javascript float calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point-precision

I have problem with calcualting float values via javascript.

first my code

```
var d_val = 0.00;
$.each($('.prices a b'), function(index,obj){
    d_val = parseFloat( $(obj).text().replace( '€', '' ) );
    group_price +=   d_val;
});
console.log( '-----> '+ group_price );
```

when i run this code when adding new elements into ".prices" firebug prints...

```
-----> 0.8
-----> 1.6
-----> 2.4000000000000004
-----> 3.2
```

$('.prices a b') has alltime a string like 0.80€ or 0.50€
Does somebody has an idea, what the problem is?

Comment: floating point numbers are almost NEVER exact values. treat them like the Borg from star trek. "We are Floating Point of Borg. Accuracy is futile. You will be approximated".

Comment: `1.6 + 0.8 === 2.4000000000000004; // true` Work in eurocents, divide out `100` as the last step, for example `160 + 80 === 240` then `240 / 100 === 2.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var mycurrency = ['0.80€', '0.60€', '0.50€', '0.506€'], sum = 0;
 $.each(mycurrency, function(i, obj){
 var myval = parseFloat(obj.replace('€', '')).toFixed(2);
 console.log('--->', myval);
 sum += parseFloat(myval);
 });
 console.log('--->', sum, '(Sum)');
```

> ### ---> 0.80
>
> ### ---> 0.60
>
> ### ---> 0.50
>
> ### ---> 0.51
>
> ### ---> 2.41 (Sum)